# Curved and Draggable Carousel in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, three.js, frontend, carousel, react-three-fiber

**Hey everyone, I have a Reactjs project where I would like to develop a draggable curved carousel. I managed to create a "smooth" slider with Threejs & Reactjs :**
[Smooth Draggable Carousel](https://codesandbox.io/s/minimap-forked-wvgq8?file=/src/components/curvedVertexSheader.js).

But impossible to give it a curved shape like this :
[image]

I did a lot of research but I couldn't find anything about it in Reactjs and Threejs. There may be a vertexSheader to put somewhere or a library.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that in the vertex shader. You must use a bend factor and transform Z based on the UV to achieve your desired result. I have something here.

Like that, I'm using a simple MeshBasicMaterial:

```
material.onBeforeCompile = shader => {

  shader.uniforms.time = { value: 0 };

  shader.vertexShader = `
    uniform float time;
    ${shader.vertexShader}
  `;

  shader.vertexShader = shader.vertexShader.replace(
    '#include <begin_vertex>',
    `
      vec3 pos = position.xyz;
      float bendFactor = ${bendFactor.toFixed(1)};

      vec2 uv2 = uv - 0.5;
      pos.z = bendFactor * pow(uv2.x, 2.);

      vec3 transformed = vec3( pos );
    `
  );

  material.userData.shader = shader;
};
```